# How to set Background color to a filtered row in Google Sheets using GAS/App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, background-color

I have a google sheets file where I filter rows based on a single column criteria. if certain cell in a column is empty, I filter that entire row. But right now my problem is that I am trying to set Background color to the filtered row. But I keep getting this error: "TypeError: rows.filter(...).setBackground is not a function" when I try the following code:

```
var mydata3 = rows.filter(row => row[8] == '').setBackground("red");
```

Does anyone know how I can achieve this or is there any work around? Because I can see that setBackground is not the data type as mydata3 which is basically a filtered row.

Thanks.

```
   var sss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0]; 
   var sheetID = sss.getSheetId(); // get the id of first page
   var values = sss.getDataRange().getValues();
   var getRangeRow2 = sss.getDataRange().getRow()[5]; 
   var getRangeCol2 = sss.getDataRange().getColumn()[1]; 
   function insertRecord() {  
      var sheet_1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];
      var headerRowNumber = 3;
      var rows = sheet_1.getDataRange().offset(headerRowNumber, 0, sheet_1.getLastRow() - 
      headerRowNumber).getValues();
      var mydata3 = rows.filter(row => row[8] == '');
   }
```

Comment: Why not use formula [tag:gs-conditional-formatting]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
function insertRecord() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheets()[0];
  const rg=sh.getRange(3,1,sh.getLastRow()-2,sh.getLastColumn());
  let vs=rg.getValues()
  var rows=vs.map(function(r,i){
    if(r[8]=='') {
      sh.getRange(i+3,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).setBackground('#ff0000');
      return r;
    }
  }).filter(function(e){return e;});
  console.log(rows);
}
```

Comment: Sorry bro but this didn't work. All I am trying to do is to take the filtered row and change its background color.

Comment: sorry cooper one more question. Is there a way I can sort the background colored rows too? Thanks.

Comment: If I understand what your asking you would have to sort the data based upon background colors and you would also at the same time sort the background colors so that they would move with the data.  You might be able to do that with a sort function.

Comment: Here is what I got as far as the sort function currently but dont know how to tell it to sort red colored rows:

SORT_DATA_RANGE = "A4:J999";
var SORT_ORDER = [{column: 8, ascending: true}];

function multiSortColumns(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
  var SORT_DATA_RANGE = "A4:I"; 
  
  var range = sheet.getRange(SORT_DATA_RANGE);
  
  range.sort(SORT_ORDER);
  ss.toast('Sort complete.');
}

Comment: I was talking about sort the data arrays and the background arrays from getValues() and getBackgrounds();